# contains clause sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

Assume that I had the following t-sql:

`select * from customer where contains(suburb, '"mount*"')`.

Now it brings back both: "Mount Hills" and "Blue Mountain". How do I strict it to search only the very beginning of the word which in this case is only "Mount Hills"?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

'contains' is used for exactly that. Use

```
select * from customer where charindex('mount', suburb)=1
```

or

```
select * from customer where suburb like 'mount%'
```

but that's slower.

Comment: hhmm... the word 'mount' is an example only. the actual input is vary and not limited to teh word "mount"..

Comment: Wouldn't you just use charindex(@variablename, suburb)=1  in that case?

Answer (score -1):

Your query works correctly, you asked server "give me all record where ANY word in column 'suburb'" starts with 'mount'.
You need to be more specific what are you trying to accomplish. Match beginning of the entire value stored in column? LIKE is your friend then.